# Mod_Security / Haproxy / Web servers (IIS)

Tags: centos, request, filtering, haproxy, mod-security

I have haproxy as a load balance  in front of my web servers(IIS), that works well.

Now I want to have mod_security configured with apache for request filtering and then pass the request to haproxy for load balancing.

I have already installed mod_security on centos, now how can I tell my WAF(mod_security) to forward request to haproxy.

Answer (score 0):

okay I got it solved... add following lines to the httpd.conf file

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests off
ProxyVia Off
ProxyPass / http://x.x.x.x:80/
ProxyPassReverse / http://x.x.x.x:80/
```

Note: Replace x.x.x.x with your actual IP